# MediaPlayerElement don't play sound on Pc, but does on Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-store-apps

I have set a MediaPlayerElement in the XAML, and I play some sounds from Music folder, It works when I test it on The phone, but not on my computer with this error message:

### Error: Unsupported video type or file path

I have google it around for a while, some suggestions said that the app should be installed to be able to access files (like the Music file)

This is the XAML:

```
<MediaPlayerElement Name="mediaPlayerElement" AutoPlay="False" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

As for the C#:

```
private void playSound(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {// triggered when I click a sound
            var soundToPlay = (Sound)e.ClickedItem;
            mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(this.BaseUri, soundToPlay.Path.ToString()));
            mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);;
        }
```

```
public class Sound
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        public ImageSource Poster { get; set; }
    }// and there is a class to get List<Sound>
```

When I debugged this code; It turns out that

```
soundToPlay
```

points to the exact location of the sound!

Comment: I ran  your code on both the phone and computer,which are not work.So can you tell me your phone’s OS version?
About the method “MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(this.BaseUri, soundToPlay.Path.ToString()));”,your error is related to “path”. We recommend you to use “mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(videoFile);” to replace the previous one.
If you have any specific reason that you have to use “path” , I hope you can tell us  the reason and more about this specific scenario.Thanks!

Comment: My phones's version is 1607, as for the method i have used; it was used in a video series so..., I have changed that method to the one suggested by @BarryWang-MSFT now It works, Thanks.

Comment: OK. Glad to know it works for you. To make this more clear to also some other communities, I've wrote the answer out.

Comment: By the way, actually when testing we cannot even use your code on phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error info is saying "Unsupported video type or file path", so first of all, the workaround for this issue is to using storagefile instead of path:

```
mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(videoFile);
```

And actually we need to avoid using path. UWP using StorageItems classes (i.e. StorageFolder and StorageFile) which has full privilege to files through a broker process. It represent a file but it is not restricted to file system objects,the app deals with the StorageFile and doesn’t need to know or care if the data originated on disk or in another app. In this way, your working with files are more easier.